# HTML Drop Down List to Select Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem that I'm hoping to get some direction in solving - I'm building an eCommerce site that includes a page displaying product options.  One of the options is selecting the product's color by selecting a swatch.  Once the swatch is selected, using JQuery, a red border goes on the selected swatch.  At the same time, the same color option is selected in an HTML drop down list/menu, which works perfectly.  The problem comes when I want the reverse done:  when a user selects the option from the drop down list, I need the corresponding swatch to have a border on it.  Not my choice, but that's the way the customer wants it.

I've looked everywhere that I can but none of the solutions I've found seem to work.  Any guidance on this one?

The JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.checkboxes input').each(function(index, value)
        {
            $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="color" color="' + $(this).attr('color') + '" style="background: url(\'../../../../images/textiles/' + $(this).attr('color') + '.jpg\')"> </div');
        });

        $('.color').click(function(e){
            //alert($(this).attr('color'));
            $('.color').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('input[color=' + $(this).attr('color') + ']').click();
        });
    });
```

The html radio buttons and drop down list:

```
<div class="checkboxes">

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void 
goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'Multicam')" color="multicam" name="color"  
value="Multicam" style="visibility: hidden"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void 
goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'Marpat')" color="marpat" name="color" 
value="Marpat" style="visibility: hidden"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'UC')" 
color="UC" name="color" value="UC"style="visibility: hidden"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void 
goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'Coyote')" color="coyote" name="color" 
value="Coyote" style="visibility: hidden"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void 
goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'Khaki')" color="khaki" name="color" value="Khaki" 
style="visibility: hidden"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void 
goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'Foliage')" color="foliage" name="color" 
value="Foliage" style="visibility: hidden"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:void 
goToOption(document.gobag.color_list,'Black')" color="black" name="color" value="Black" 
style="visibility: hidden" />

</div></span><br />

    <select name="color_list" onchange="">
    <option selected="selected">Select a Color</option>
    <option name="Black" >Black</option>
    <option name="Foliage" >Foliage</option>
    <option name="Khaki" >Khaki</option>
    <option name="Coyote" >Coyote</option>
    <option name="UC" >UC</option>
    <option name="Marpat" >Marpat</option>
    <option name="Multicam" >Multicam</option>
    </select><br /><br />
```

Comment: Do you have any code? Can you show it please?

Comment: how does the swatch relate to the option ?

Comment: The swatch and option are related in that they are the same in terms of Value and Name, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('select[name="color_list"]').change(function() {
  $('input[color=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('checked',true);
});
```

This is using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the radio button as checked, and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value from the selected `option`

or using `prop('name')` instead of `val()` on the `option`

`$('input[color=' + $(this).prop('name') + ']').prop('checked',true);`

or if using jQuery < 1.6 - you cannot use `prop`, you have to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

`$('input[color=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('checked','checked');`

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gu5Ug/)

Looking at your site - the problem is clear :

```
$('select[name="color_list"]').change(function() {
    $('.color').removeClass('selected');                                           
    $('.color').addClass('selected');
    $('input[color=' + $(this).attr('color') + ']').prop('checked',true);
});
```

your adding the `selected` class to every swatch, change it to this :

```
$('select[name="color_list"]').change(function() {
    $('.color').removeClass('selected');                                           
    $('div[color=' + $(this).attr('color') + ']').addClass('selected');
    $('input[color=' + $(this).attr('color') + ']').prop('checked',true);
});
```

this only adds the class to the correct swatch. (note you might have to lowercase the value from the option)

Comment: I think this is the right track, but I can't seem to get it working with everything... I'm including it with the JQuery code that I have above and the swatch doesn't seem to change.

Comment: @jbrown574 could you create a http://jsfiddle.net with your code ? or debug it and tell me the problem ? its quite difficult to help without knowing what the issue is !

Comment: After trying to get all the pieces to work in JSFiddle, I gave up.  I can give you the url to the page in my beta test area so you can get a better idea for what I'm trying to do: http://zeropointusa.dpigraphics.net/Products/Systems/RenderSafePackage(RSP)/TacticalIEDKits(TIK)/tik1.php

Comment: I did as you suggested, still having issues with it working.  To clarify - lowercase the value in the drop down list <option>, right?  Currently, there is no value set in the option tag.

Comment: I'm getting a "undefined" error for this line: $('div[color=' + $(this).attr('color') + ']').addClass('selected');

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking to capture the drop down (select) change event. Singe you're already using jQuery, you could put something like this in your pages `document.ready()` method to capture that event:

```
$('#colorDropDown').change(function() {
  // Add the red border to your swatch.
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple questions for you so we can get this nailed down:

-thanks for the code!

As for direction in general, I think you need to attach whatever javascript machinery you have to place the border on the appropriate swatch, on the 'onchange' attribute of your dropdown. Your code might look something like this:

HTML

```
<select name=yourdropdown onchange='selectSwatch(this.form.yourdropdown);'>
```

Javascript

```
function selectSwatch(dropdown){
     // code to change the swatch...like some of these other guys' answers!
     // They have a lot more experience than I do!
}
```

Kind Regards,

sf

Comment: That's kind of what I was figuring...there needed to be an onchange event for the drop down...